# Split string of numbers with no whitespaces in python

Tags: python, string, split, format

I have a string of numbers with no whitespaces like this:

```
s = '12.2321.4310.85'
```

I know that the format for each number is F5.2 (I am reading the string from a FORTRAN code output)

I need to obtain the following list of numbers based on `s`:

```
[12.23,21.43,10.85]
```

How can I do this in python?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is something very very wrong with whatever is giving this data to you. Fix that instead of writing hacks to deal with it.

Comment: @cs95 This is from a text file output from a model written in FORTRAN. I am reading the text file because I need to modify this string of numbers later.

Comment: Slice the string into chunks of 5 characters.  Convert each chunk to `float`.

Comment: Yup, that's my idea too! @Prune

Comment: BTW, what you've listed is FORTRAN format specification F5.2, not 4.2.  It's total field width at the front.

Comment: @Prune thank you...I just clarified this in the post

Comment: Now ... is there any chance that you'll  get an overrun of that 5-char field?  For instance, could you get '12.2321.431023.85', with the final value being `1023.85`?  If so, the problem turns into something harder.

Comment: @Prune no, in that case, I would have something like '  12.23  21.431023.85'....the format in this case would be F7.2 I think...

Comment: Great; in that case, my posted answer should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice the string into chunks of 5 characters. Convert each chunk to float.

```
>>> [float(s[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(s), 5)]
[12.23, 21.43, 10.85]
```

Comment: There might be numbers like 1234.56 and 78.99 in the dataset using format 4.2 and generate s = "1234.5678.99"

Comment: Thank you @Prune, this works for me since I know the number of characters from the FORTRAN format.

Comment: @aminrd I just clarified with OP that this is *not* the case.  Strict FORTRAN does not overrun the output field as other languages do ... often to my annoyance in college days.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure of the format, and that will always be handed in that way then using a `step` of 5 in your loop might work:

```
s = '12.2321.4310.85'
output = []
for i in range(0,len(s),5):
    output.append(float(s[i:i+5]))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[12.23, 21.43, 10.85]
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but couldn't format `4.2` generate something like `1234.56` in python?

Comment: Yes, the size of 5 assumes there's 2 decimal places, 1 ones and 1 tens.

Comment: My point is, there might be numbers like `1234.56` and `78.99` in the dataset using format `4.2` and generate `s = "1234.5678.99"`

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified the condition in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way is to rely on `.` points. Because we know that every floating point should have one fraction and always there are two fraction numbers (there might be values like `1234.56` and `78.99` in the data that generates `s = "1234.5678.99"`). But we are not sure how many digits are before `.`. So we can extract values one by one based on `.`.

```
s = '12.2321.4310.85'
def extractFloat(s):
    # Extracts the first floating number with 2 floatings from the string
    return float( s[:s.find('.')+3]) , s[s.find('.')+3:]

l = []
while len(s) > 0:
    value, s = extractFloat(s)
    l.append(value)

print(l)
# Output: 
# [12.23, 21.43, 10.85]
```